# PHP include path query

Tags: php, html

Root Folder

|

|-----Admin folder (in root folder)

|Admin         |-----factory.php (in admin folder)

|Admin         |-----Object0.php(in admin folder)

|Admin         |-----object1.php(in admin folder)

|Admin         |-----admin.php(in admin folder)

|

|-----utils.php (in root folder)

|-----index.php (in root folder)

index.php is using factory class to retrive data , included using

```
include_once("admin/factory.php")
```

utils.php for general purpose , and so i kept in main folder, factory.php included this file using

```
include_once("utils.php").
```

admin.php is using factory class to submit data,  included using

```
include_once("factory.php")
```

but it prompt me warning for not able to open utils.php.

How we need to go for such approach, there may be chances for few more folders in future, how we should add these.

how other files like js, css, images will be references in HTML. it would be good if anyone provide me best input on that

one approach is to reference everything by root. but how ?

Comment: include like this in factory.php it will search one step outside  from current directory include_once("../utils.php").

Comment: thanks... but what should be best approach we need to follow.

Comment: Why not use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` with the full path? Then, you could include factory.php anywhere and it still would work.

Comment: @dnLL Sometimes $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is not set or if you work under CLI definetely will not be set. Also it could be with wrong configuration and etc... It's easier and safer with the way I explained bellow.

Comment: I actually never had to manage yet with inclusions within inclusions with different folder paths, but thank you, it will be useful if I ever have to.

Answer (score 3):

Add the below code to a file in the root directory,  and  include the file at the top of all the main scripts.

```
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Then you can use the following includes in any of your files

```
include_once ABSPATH.'admin/factory.php';
include_once ABSPATH.'utils.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try including utils.php in admin.php:

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../utils.php';
```

`__FILE__` is always the file you're on, no matter where you included from and `dirname()` gets its directory.

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php